# Saturated BJT Transistors. \$V_{CE} < V_{BE}\$ : AKA - Things that make you go "Hmmmm"

Tags: transistors, bjt, physics

We use them every day and those in the know fully understand the functional characteristics of BJT transistors. There are documents and links galore explaining the operational math. There are even tons of nice videos that explain current theories of how they physically work. ( Most of the latter given by folks that speak "Tele-marketer English" for some reason. )

However, I have to admit, even after 40+ years, a lot of it I have to accept at face value, since the descriptions of how the collector junction fits into the equation is always a bit hand-wavy.

Anyhow, that aside, there is one facet I really just don't get. It seems to defy the laws of physics, Kirchhoff's Laws et.al.

I'm talking about your standard saturated common emitter circuit.

It is known, and we accept, that when saturated, the collector voltage will be less than the base voltage. We obviously use that to our advantage in circuits and chose parts to give us as low a Vce-Sat as possible for a particular load current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmNBLv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All fine and dandy, till you look at the quintessential mode of a typical NPN transistor...

[image]

How the heck can the collector be a lower voltage than the base in that sandwich?

Even if you add in some back-EMF type voltage in there to account for it, the collector current would be going the wrong way through the base-collector junction..

Comment: Does it help to think of the electrons as building momentum as they accelerate across Vbe, which carries them completely through the (very narrow) base region into the collector? (like freewheeling on your bike downhill and up the next (smaller) hill, missing the right turn onto a narrow track at the bottom?

Comment: Looks like you might need to descend few levels of abstraction ...

Comment: @BrianDrummond ya that's the classical hand wavy answers I was talking about that bypass the basic laws of EE. That somehow they pop over without and Ohmic effect..

Comment: Yeah. You have base emitter current. You have base collector current. And you have collector emitter current. The base collector current is low until you go into saturation. The reason base current increases (with Ic held constant) in saturation is that some of the current takes a shortcut to the base by going to the collector instead.

Comment: @mkeith heard that before too. but it makes no sense either, The current has to end up at the emitter. Base current going to the collector would need to turn around and head back through the base to the emitter.

Comment: It is not turning around. It is just going out through a different exit.

Comment: @mkeith how... the collector goes up, eventually, to some high voltage >Vb... it's sure not going THAT way.

Comment: Remember that (for NPN) the emitter supplies electrons, the base supplies holes... in saturation, both end up in the collector, they simply recombine there.

Comment: It might be interesting to put a low value resistor between the collector and **ground** and measure how much current flows to ground through the collector vs. the expected path (through the grounded emitter).

Comment: LOL I posted this in physics too... they sent it back.. Ha.

Comment: With Vce=0.5V your transistor doesn't have to be saturated, in fact if the collector current is not too high, it would be working in quasi-saturation, and its performance would still be quite good...

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386826/2451

Answer (score 6):

In a bipolar transistor, the emitter has a much higher doping than the base. When you apply a forward bias to the base-emitter diode, current will flow, and due to the higher doping in the emitter, a lot more electrons flow from the emitter into the base than holes flow from the base into the emitter.

Current in a semiconductor can flow via two major mechanisms: There's "drift" current, where an electric field accelerates electrons in a certain direction. That's the simple way of current flow we're all used to. There's also "diffusion" current, where electrons move from areas of higher electron concentration into areas of lower concentration, much like water soaking into a sponge. However, those diffusing electrons can't move around forever since they will, at some point, hit a hole and recombine. That means diffusing (free) electrons in a semiconductor have a half-life and a so-called diffusion length, which is the average distance they travel before recombining with a hole.

Diffusion is the mechanism by which a diode junction creates its depletion region.

Now, if the base-emitter diode is forward-biased, the depletion region of the base-emitter diode gets smaller and electrons begin to diffuse from this junction into the base. However, since the transistor is built so that the diffusion length of those electrons is longer than the base is wide, a lot of those electrons are actually able to diffuse right through the base without recombining and come out at the collector, effectively "tunneling" through the base by not interacting with the holes there. (Recombination is a random process and doesn't happen immediately, which is why diffusion exists in the first place.)

So in the end, some electrons end up in the collector by random movement. Now that they are there, the electrons can only get back into the base when they overcome the forward bias voltage of the base-collector diode, causing them to "pile up" in the collector, decreasing the voltage there, until they can overcome the base-collector junction and flow back. (In reality, this process is an equilibrium, of course.)

With the voltages you apply to the base, emitter and collector, you only create the electric fields in the semiconductor that cause drift of electrons towards the depletion region, changing the concentration of electrons in the crystal, which then results in diffusion current flowing through the base. While single electrons are influenced by the electric fields created by the voltages at the transistor's terminals, they do not themselves have a voltage, only energy levels. Within a part of the crystal that is generally at the same voltage, electrons can (and will) have different energy. In fact, no two electrons can ever have the same energy level.

This also explains why transistors can work in reverse, but with much less current gain: It is harder for electrons to diffuse into the highly doped emitter region than into the lightly doped collector since the electron concentration is rather high there already. That makes this path less favorable for electrons than in the non-reversed transistor, so more electrons just flow straight out of the base and the gain is lower.

Comment: Jonathon, that is all very well, and classic, but it does not explain how you can have a layer in the middle that is at a higher voltage than the one above it.

Comment: @Trevor_G In a semiconductor, there aren't really "voltages". There are electric fields, but single electrons can have many different energy levels even though they're in the same area of the crystal. If that wasn't the case, there wouldn't be band gaps and therefore no semiconductors. An electron does not even have a voltage.

Comment: @JonathanS.: See my answer. Understanding the detail that Trevor is talking about requires an understanding that the fields/voltages associated with the base are not constant across its area, especially during saturation.

Comment: I have read all this before, it still does not explain how the voltage can be lower at the collector, only how electrons make it through the depletion regions. Though you did briefly elude to tunnelling.

Comment: @Trevor_G The base is positively doped, the collector slightly negative. Since the base is small compared to the diffusion length of the electrons, we can assume an equal amount of electrons *per area* "lands" in the base and collector after diffusing. Since the collector is already negatively doped, it will have a larger concentration of electrons than the base, causing it to be at a lower voltage.

Comment: @JonathanS. I'm sure you have it here somewhere, I just find the middle part a bit unclear .. starting with "The electrons are able to do this because..."

Comment: BTW THe whole "already negatively doped, it will have a larger concentration of electrons than the base" also does not make any sense to me. Being doped means it is willing to either release or accept electrons, there is not net charge/voltage simply from being doped.

Comment: @Trevor_G I edited the answer again, it should be much clearer now. I have to admit that that paragraph of my answer was a little bad.

Comment: Thats better thanks.. So anyway.... do I take it you are saying something like, the majority of the electrons effectively pass through the thin base layer to the collector without interacting with it, and that the base acts more like a screen in a valve. As such the resistance path from emitter to collector is < resistance path from emitter to base when saturated?

Comment: @Trevor_G Yes, they do pass through the base by diffusion because the chance of randomly hitting a hole and recombining in the base is low. A bipolar transistor does indeed behave quite similar to a triode with a positive screen voltage - if an electron hits the screen, it flows out, but the chance of hitting it is low. You can't really speak of a resistance though - it's the diffusion (electron) current into the collector being in equilibrium with the exponential base-collector diode current causing the voltage drop (or rather voltage generation).

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes I was using resistance for lack of a better word to keep it simple.

Comment: So again, if I may... just to make sure I am on the same page... looking at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB0ua.png) you are saying the base draws electrons out through the holes (as it were) .. but the predominance of electrons blow past them into the collector where most of them leave, however, the collector is now being driven lower than Vb (the base being sort of shorted out), as such the some electrons will return to the base, basically turning on the Vbc diode, setting Vce sat < Vb, and balancing the base current so it all that reaches some equilibrium condition?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73276/discussion-between-jonathan-s-and-trevor-g).

Answer (score 5):

> How the heck can the collector be a lower voltage than the base in
>   that sandwich?

There's no law of physics that prevents the collector from being at a lower voltage than the base: apply \$0.7\,\mathrm{V}\$ between B and E, apply \$0.4\,\mathrm{V}\$ between C and E, and you'll bias the BJT in exactly that condition.

Therefore, your real question is probably: *Given those applied voltages, how come that the law of physics allow the collector current to flow into the collector?*

Kirchhoff's laws applied to the BJT imply only that 
$$-V_\mathrm{BE}-V_\mathrm{CB}+V_\mathrm{CE}=0$$
and
$$I_\mathrm{C}+I_\mathrm{B}+I_\mathrm{E}=0,$$
where I assumed terminal currents as positive when entering into the terminals.

Furthermore, since there's no source of energy inside the BJT, we require the power entering the device to be positive (I consider a static case, neglecting dynamical effects to avoid the subtleties of passivity), that is,
$$V_\mathrm{BE}I_\mathrm{B}+V_\mathrm{CE}I_\mathrm{C}>0.$$

These are the only constraints that physics puts on the terminal voltages and currents in the static case. As you can see, all the above conditions hold for a saturated BJT.

Your confusion probably comes from implicitly assuming a *linear* device, which a BJT is not.

Comment: Thanks for copying over your answer, I deleted the duplicate before your answer appeared sorry.

Comment: btw the above is correct of course but was not really the question... thanks anyway.

Comment: @Trevor_G The answer is all in the last line ;-) When you write "the collector current would be going the wrong way through the base-collector junction" you're thinking as though between C and E there is a resistor.

Comment: It appears that the origin of the confusion is assuming that current can only be a drift current. Diffusion current does not have to obey the electric field, actually it's the fact that it can flow _despite_ an opposing electric field that make transistors capable of... transistor action.

Comment: @SredniVashtar Right, you expressed better than me what's probably in OP's mind. In suggesting linearity I oversimplified the situation.

Comment: @SredniVashtar yes that's the current theory, but my issue is HOW? How can electrons move despite the opposing electric field when there is no measurable energy source and no measurable terminal voltage induced by that migration.

Comment: @Trevor_G From your comments, I suspect that you think that the transport of electrons is driven by the electric field only, that is, the gradient of the electrical potential. Actually, what drives the electron transport is the _electrochemical potential_, which takes into account the inhomogeneity of the system, due to the varying carrier concentrations across the junctions. It's this inhomogeneity that generates the diffusion current.

Comment: @Trevor_G , As Massimo said, it's the gradient in concentration that gives rise to a diffusion current. Much in the same way a gas can expand upwards _despite_ gravity. Electrons in a semiconductor are more like a gas (you can move them with a pump, but they can also move because of a concentration gradient) , while in a conductor they are more like a liquid (being incompressible, you need a pump to make it move). It appears to me you are asking: how can I have this gas move without a pump pushing in that direction?

Comment: Also, if somehow you managed to remove that diffusion current component, for example by placing a layer of conductor in the middle of the base, you would instantly 'condensate' that gas in a liquid, that by being swept out of the base would kill the transistor action. You'll end up with two diodes back to back, and in that case your objection on potentials would be valid. Problem is, you could not reach the same values of current and potentials you have in a transistor.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano actually I do understand diffusion current, or think I do. What I don't get is in a pn-junction, a diode, we state that diffusion current forms a potential barrier because holes and electrons pair up forming a voltage difference. Which all makes perfect sense, until you put a voltmeter across an out of circuit diode. No such voltage is measurable. Even if you accept it at face value in a transistor, it does not explain how the electrons make it past the reverse biased collector diode in a non-saturated state.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano continued: The explanation, though obviously pertinent and related, leaves some large grey areas that are brushed over because it just works.

Comment: @Trevor_G it looks like you live in a 0 K universe. Carriers have a spectrum of energies due to T>0 K. So the carriers able to cross the barrier are those in the tail of the Fermi-Dirac distribution (which, being approximated by a Boltzmaniann distribution, give rise to an exponential dependence).

Comment: @SredniVashtar now you are starting to talk in a more physics description rather than a wishy washy description :). Which is good, and what I am looking for. You should expand that into an actual answer. :D

Comment: @Trevor_G I think it would be better for you to update your question to clarify your doubts. In fact, initially, your question talked about Kirchhoff's Laws and not about the device physics (which is why I wrote this answer this way, to show you that the laws of circuit theory are not in contrast with the device behaviour).  Only after this long series of comments I understand that the main focus is on electron transport, that is, on what drives the motion of the electrons so that the device actually works the way it does. You might even think of asking a different, more focussed question.

Comment: You may be right about that, but your answer is still pertinent in so much as the math still works out, but it's the how it gets into that state that is the real question.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that the base does not have the same voltage throughout its area. There is an irreducible "sheet" resistance associated with the base, whose external connection must necessarily be at the edge of the structure in some sense. Since there is a current distribution within that "sheet", there is also a voltage distribution.

So, in saturation, the current that flows into the base terminal goes through both forward-biased diode junctions (B-E and B-C), near the base terminal. The current that went to the collector then flows to the emitter through a different part of the base that is farther away from the base terminal.

In essence, the voltage drop across the inherent base resistance is what allows the voltage distribution that we see at the external terminals.

Comment: Ya I though that might be something like that too, but then I realised if that were the case the farther away points would not be forward biased and not conducting, so the idea kind of falls apart.

Comment: No, it doesn't fall apart. There's no reason that some regions can't be forward biased while others are not. Stop thinking in terms of lumped circuit elements -- the fields vary continuously within a transistor, especially during saturation. The parts that are not forward-biased are functioning in the "classical" manner that Jonathan S. described.

Answer (score 0):

BJT's are current devices.  When in the active region, lot's of the emitter's (emitters are heavily doped and more negative than the base) electrons go into the base (lightly doped) and some fall into the fewer base holes, but most diffuse across to the collector, causing Ic.  When saturated, the collector is also more negative than the base, so it contributes some electrons to the base.  As the collector contributes more electrons to the base (Vbc is more positive), it follows that collector-emitter current will be lower.  As Vbc gets smaller (Vce(sat) is higher), the saturation current can be higher.  So once in saturation, the collector voltage goes up with collector current.

You can run a transistor with the collector and emitter reversed.  Since the collector is lightly doped compared to the emitter, gain is lousy, but Vce(sat) will be down in the single mV range.  In the pre-FET era, we used this approach to ground analog inputs in sample-and holds, etc.

Answer (score 0):

NON-RECTIFYING JUNCTION POTENTIALS.  That's the trick.

Everyone's missing a simple, very basic fact.  (Most beginner textbooks miss this too.  Even some engineering profs seem clueless.)  The fact:  *junctions always have a voltage across them,* even when unpowered, even when it's metal-silicon with no diode effect  ...and even when the junction is iron-copper, chromel-alumel, etc.

In other words, if we want to understand everything about diodes and transistors, we're not allowed to ignore thermocouple physics and NON-RECTIFYING JUNCTIONS.   If we do, then Vce becomes unexplainable, a dark mystery of engineering.

[more to come]

Answer (score -1):

Ideally the Vbe matches the Vcb and both are forward conductng with Vce(sat)=0 at Imax and Ic/Ib=10.

As Dave T. pointed out the Vbe base spreading resistance (aka effective series R or ESR)  is not uniform but by making multiple narrow base wells in parallel the performance improves.

When the ESR of the smaller higher doped B-E junction is higher than the larger ESR of the C-B junction we get a higher Vbe than Vcb thus Vce(sat) rises. THe current gain has now dropped to about 10% of max.

- The epitaxial process is usually planar than vertical.
- ion implantation is used for the emitter and base junctions.
- the collector emittor current is increased thru a buried n+ layer to reduce the CE resistance or \$R_{CE}\$
- many more electrons injcted into base than holes into emitter
- since the base is made very narrow, most emitter electrons travel thru base and reach the collector

[image]

Zetex invented  about 100 process patents around this epitaxial technology and now as Diodes Inc has many products although more expensive have similar dies sizes with Rce in the 10's of milliohms intead of obsolete TO-3 cans with Rce in the 1 Ohm range. This reduces the heat dissipation of at high currents significantly.

ON Semi have their own low Vce(sat) parts too.

This SOT-23 is <13 cents in volume and has Rce=45 mOhm max. Vce max= 12V

[image]

Comment: What is the problem? The base voltage creates the field for CE to conduct

Comment: No intelligent rebuttal -1